# Chosen plugin change doesnt work on page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

My problem is : i'm using chosen plugin. 2 select boxes. When selecting the first selectbox option, in second selectbox values are filtered. it works fine. But when i am reloading page with ajax, the first select box value selected right but looks like it is not active, it cannot filter second select box value. I tried to simulate change event, tried to trigger the select box, but i had no luck.

I will show some source code:

Ajax call:

```
    function loadContent(url){
var slidersGetUrl = "&slider1="+slider1Val1+"&slider2="+slider1Val2+"&slider3="+slider1Val3+"&slider4="+slider1Val4+"&slider5="+slider1Val5+"&slider6="+slider1Val6;

            var planUrl = "&plan="+selectedplan;
            var paymentPeriodUrl = "&billing="+selectedpaymentperiod;
            var cpUrl = "&cp="+selectedcp;
            var osUrl = "&os="+selectedos;

            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "aa/aa/aa/aa.php" + url + slidersGetUrl + planUrl + paymentPeriodUrl + cpUrl + osUrl,
                //url: url,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#plans-block').html('loading...');
                },
                success: function(data){
                       $('#plans-block').html("");
                       $('#plans-block').html(data);
                      //$('#ajax-wrap').slideToggle();
                      //console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                  $('#plans-block').html("Failed. Please reload the page!");
                }
              });
        }
```

Then i have big HTML block in ajax called file where select boxes are made

This is my select box 1 :

```
<select id="cp" name="cp">
                    <option value="-1"><?php echo $_LANG['none'] ?></option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($controlpanels as $cp):
                        $os_price = (float) $cp['price'];
                        if ($os_price < 0)
                            continue;
                        ?>
                        <option data-price="<?php echo $os_price; ?>" data-bc="<?php echo $cp['bc']; ?>" value="<?php echo $cp['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($cp['id'] == $_GET['cp'] ? 'selected' : '') ?>><?php echo $cp['name']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
```

Then i have javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        ...

        $('#cp').change(function () {
            $($(this)).children().each(function (i, j) {
                if ($(this).val() > 0)
                    order.removeAdittionalProduct($(this).val());
            });

            if ($(this).val() > 0)
                updatePrice(
                        order.addAdittionalProduct($(this).val(), $(this).children('[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('data-bc'), $(this).children('[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('data-price'), {}, {})
                        );
            else
                updatePrice(order.getPrice().toFixed(2));
        });

$("#cp").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10, width: "245px"});
        $('#cp').on('change', function () {
            if ($("#cp").val() != -1) {
                // Removing all none centos from OS
                $("#os option").each(function ()
                {
                    if ($(this).val() != -1)
                    {
                        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("centos") == -1)
                            $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
                $('#os').val('-1');
                $('#os').trigger('change');
                $('#os').trigger("liszt:updated");

                $('#cp_chzn .chzn-single span').css("color", "#444444");
            }
            else {
                // Remove all but first
                $('#os option:gt(0)').remove();
                // Add all default OS
                $.each(os_arr, function (i, elem) {
                    $("#os").append('<option data-price="0.00" value="' + elem['id'] + '">' + elem['name'] + '</option>');
                });
                $('#os').val('-1');
                $('#os').trigger('change');
                $('#os').trigger("liszt:updated");

                $('#cp_chzn .chzn-single span').css("color", "#8d9aab");
            }
        });

        ...
        });
```

This is the image when  i changed value in first selectbox manually, everything works as it should.
[image]

This is the image after ajax call, when html was loaded again. In the image you can see that first select box select value is gray, while in first image that value is black, so my desition is that, after ajax call value was not `$('#cp').trigger('change').` affected, and in second select box you can see that there are more options, that means values was not filtered.
[image]

I have tried a lot of things in other posts people were suggested, but it doesnt work.
I've just tested some code in console window and it worked is this:

```
$('#cp').change();
$('#cp').on('change', function () {
        $('#cp').val('129');
    });
```

But when i'm adding it to my page code it doesnt work.

These doesnt work either :

```
$('#cp').trigger('change');
$('#cp').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

**UPDATE**

Problems is solved. `$('#cp').val('<?php echo $_GET['cp']; ?>').trigger("change");` this function needs to be at the bottom of the document ready function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using delegated event handlers attached to parts of the page *that do not change*:

```
$(document).on('change', '#cp', function () {
    $('#cp').val('129');
});
```

A delegated event works by listening for events bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor. `document` is the default if there is nothing convenient/closer. It *then* applies the jQuery selector to the elements in the bubble chain. It *then* calls the function *for any matching element that caused the event*. This means the element does not have to match until event time, rather than when the event handler is created.

Note: Do not use `'body'` for delegated events, as styling can cause the body to have 0 height and events may not occur! Always use `document` as the fallback.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it, but i have no luck. I have added `console.log('changed')` to debug it. but i got no debug message in console at all.

Comment: That should have fixed it (unless there is another issue, like duplicate IDs). Can you post the output HTML of your page to inspect? (not just the PHP source). Save it from your browser.

Comment: I just can show you a code from inspect element window, i cant show it from viewsource, because content is ajax loaded: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6151466/sourcetxt.txt

Comment: Start with this JSFiddle (which works with the `#cp` snippet from the page): http://jsfiddle.net/ke4vob4a/ and see if you can spot any other issues.

Comment: I have solved my problem. instead of adding this code `$('#cp').val('<?php echo $_GET['cp']; ?>').trigger("change");` at the top of the javascript code, i added it to the bottom of the page, after all other functions in document.ready and it worked. Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes, you must register event handlers before you trigger the event :)